# Rails devise invitable undefined method this

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise-invitable

I am using devise invitable in my app: a user fills a form with email, that creates a user in my database and sends an invitation to the email address. The other person can then confirm its account by setting up his password.
Everything works fine until the invited user tries to log in by setting up his password. When he submits the form, I get this error:

undefined local variable or method `this' for #

here's my invitation controller:

```
    class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new
    @user.save
  end

  def update
    if this
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      super
    end
  end

  private

  # this is called when creating invitation
  # should return an instance of resource class
  def invite_resource
    ## skip sending emails on invite
    resource_class.invite!(invite_params, current_inviter) do |u|
      u.skip_invitation = true
    end
  end

  # this is called when accepting invitation
  # should return an instance of resource class
  def accept_resource
    resource = resource_class.accept_invitation!(update_resource_params)
    ## Report accepting invitation to analytics
    Analytics.report('invite.accept', resource.id)
    resource
  end
end
```

What is this "this" thing ?

Comment: my guess is that `this` acts like `self` as in its the class itself.

Comment: Where have you taken this code from?

Comment: @pmicha the update method that brings the error is from here https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable

Comment: What happens when you remove method **update** from your controller? What you want to do in your custom update controller?

Comment: yes it does work when you remove the method update from the controller ! I dont have a clue what's going on though

Comment: @DavidGeismar, did you manage to resolve this issue? I have the same problem now!